# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 : A server with the specified hostname could not be found error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlerrordomain

I have an app where I am calling one web service which works fine for the first time but for second time `didFailWithError` gets called with error

> "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

And also a weird error like

> dnssd_clientstub deliver_request: socketpair failed 24 (Too many open files). nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue DNSServiceGetAddrInfo failed: Unknown(-65537)

I don't think it is a network issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is there your wifi or internet connection active ?

Comment: this error occur when your internet dont reach at server .check your internet connectivity

Comment: Yes it's active. the only thing is I am getting this error for 2nd or 3rd time . First time it works correctly.